# why does tinyMce escape my PHP code that i want to display on my blog?

Tags: php, html, tinymce

I'm trying to display PHP code in my blog, and I'm inserting it into tinymce textrea, but it escapes the php code? I tried doing it without tinymce and it worked, but with tinymce it doesn't? :)) thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you type the PHP directly into designer mode (the mode that shows the rendered HTML rather than the source code) TinyMCE will escape it assuming that you want to talk about the PHP rather than execute it.  This is pretty much standard behaviour for rich text editors since it matches the user expectation that they can type < and have it appear correctly on the webpage rather than acting as the start of a tag.

You want to enter the PHP code directly into the source view and ensure that the HTML filter is configured to allow PHP properly (this depends on the version of TinyMCE you use).

That said, TinyMCE really isn't designed for editing HTML that has PHP inside it - it can do it, but generally it's better to use a rich text editor for plain HTML that non-technical users would edit and a plain text area for HTML that technical authors write which may contain PHP.

Answer (score 0):

while inserting php code either insert it in designer mode or try encoding the code with htmlentities

Comment: it is inserted into designer mode!!1 :((

Answer (score 0):

i am scpaing the < and > using conditional coments on source code view

Before: 
{% if produtos|count &gt 0 %}

After add conditional comments on your code and put ">" replace "&gt"

<!-- {% if produtos|count > 0 %} -->

This working for me